# Visual Studio 2015 and Selenium: Adding chromedriver

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, selenium-chromedriver

VS never ceases to amaze me. Or, rather, it never ceases to amaze me how I either forget how to do things between each time I create a new solution, or how things seem to change in between solutions.

I'm trying to use ChromeDriver with Selenium (in C#). I've installed the Selenium.Webdriver and Selenium.Chrome NuGet packages in the project, and everything seems fine. No errors on the using directives, and no errors when trying to create a new ChromeDriver.

Here's the Selenium driver code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Threading;

...

public class GCDriver {
    public static IWebDriver Instance { get; set; }

    public static void Initialize () {
        Instance = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    public static void Wait(TimeSpan timeSpan) {
        Thread.Sleep((int)(timeSpan.TotalSeconds * 1000));
    }

    public static void Close() {
        Instance.Quit();
    }
}
```

When trying to start (initialize) the ChromeDriver as I allways do, I get this error:

```
Test Name:  One
Test FullName:  MyTests.TestUnitTest1.One
Test Source:    C:\Users\149999frho\Source\Workspaces\QA\Automation\MyTests\TestUnitTest1.cs : line 17
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00,0118783

Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.FindDriverServiceExecutable(String    executableName, Uri downloadUrl)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor()
   at Automation.GCDriver.Initialize() in C:\Users\149999frho\Source\Workspaces\QA\Automation\Automation\Selenium\GCDriver.cs:line 16
   at MyTests.TestUnitTest1.Init() in C:\Users\149999frho\Source\Workspaces\QA\Automation\MyTests\TestUnitTest1.cs:line 12
Result Message: Initialization method MyTests.TestUnitTest1.Init threw    exception. OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException:    OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: The chromedriver.exe file does    not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html..
```

The thing is, the chromedriver.exe IS located in the Solution\Project\Automation\bin\Debug folder. As it should be, since the NuGet package(s) is installed.

What am I missing here? Do I have to add any other references after installing the NuGet package? Adding the chromedriver.exe file as a reference is not possible, btw - VS complains about it not being an actual COM reference or something like that.

The references seems to be in order, though - and the references folder looks EXACTLY the same as in the other solution where things are working:

[image]

UPDATE:
I found a workaround: Adding the path to the chromedriver.exe file when creating a new instance of ChromeDriver. Instance = new ChromeDriver(). However, this is an idiotic and useless solution, as I have to use the absolute path - VS doesn't accept a relative one. When sharing a project it will be downright impossible to manage.

So the problem is that the project doesn't know where the file installed by it's own NuGet package manager resides. Argh! How is this possible with a piece of software in this price range?!

Comment: I've also experienced this. Sadly, I've never found a solution or answer. After trying again and again and again, creating new projects and solutions again and again - always identical - it ends up working in the end.